returning specific status code , message in server actions
I have this code below, What I'm trying to achieve is returning error (specific message and status code) instead of getting always 500 status code, if i tried to register with an existing email,I'm getting this error in console
Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported.
first of course i dont need to return a simple object like this cause this wont be treated as error instead it will be returning as 200 status code (ok) , so i want a way to return desired status code + message and access them normally in client to show the message in alert for example..
{ code:400, message:"User already exists" }
server code
"use server";
import { connectToDB } from "@/lib/mongodb";
import User from "@/lib/mongodb/models/User";
import * as bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const registerUser = async ({
  email,
  username,
  password,
}: RegisterParams) => {
  try {
    await connectToDB();

    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (existingUser) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "User already exists" },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const newUser = await User.create({
      username,
      email,
      password: hashedPass,
    });

    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newUser));
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
};


im using it like this in my client component
  await registerUser({ email, password, username })
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
        });


i tried to do it like this so i did access the message and it's correctly returned as error response but it was 500 not 400 .. so i need a way to customize it foreach condition if i have many conditions in my code ..
this is the code but i think it's not the best way for handling something like this
"use server";

import { connectToDB } from "@/lib/mongodb";
import User from "@/lib/mongodb/models/User";
import * as bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

class HttpError extends Error {
  constructor(public message: string, public status: number) {
    super(message);
    this.name = "HttpError";
  }
}

export const registerUser = async ({
  email,
  username,
  password,
}: RegisterParams) => {
  try {
    await connectToDB();

    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (existingUser) {
      throw new HttpError("User already exists", 400);
    }

    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const newUser = await User.create({
      username,
      email,
      password: hashedPass,
    });

    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newUser));

  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error instanceof HttpError) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      throw new HttpError("An unexpected error occurred", 500);
    }
  }
};



Do you get the 500 only for existing users?

yes ,the error is thrown correctly and the message that i got is correct but the problem is im not able to specify status code like if i wanna set it to 400
